# submit sitemap to the google

Tags: c#, asp.net, sitemap

```
 System.Net.WebRequest reqGoogle = System.Net.WebRequest.Create("http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/ping?sitemap=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode("http://www.shree/SiteMap/'" + PortalName + "'/sitemap.xml"));
 reqGoogle.GetResponse();
```

Code work fine when google is not blocked.For some region my administrator block the goole.After blocking google code gives an error. How to check the site first if it is blocked or not.plz help.

Comment: Just help me understand... what do you *want* it to do if google is not available? throwing an exception (that you can catch) seems pretty reasonable...?

Comment: (for anyone wondering, the route in the question is supported, [see here](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=183669))

Comment: @Marc Gravell No no i just want to check first if google is available or not.

Comment: but... why? the only way to do that *for sure* is to hit a url on google. It might as why be this one!

Comment: @MarcGravell Thanks a lot for clear my vision.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

like this(?):

```
try
{
  System.Net.WebRequest reqGoogle = System.Net.WebRequest.Create("http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/ping?sitemap=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode("http://www.shree/SiteMap/'" + PortalName + "'/sitemap.xml"));
  reqGoogle.GetResponse();
}
catch(WebException ex)
{
  MessageBox.Show("Google is blocked");
}
```